# How to group records by last duplicates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that holds information about users logins. I want to group the *last* duplicate records. For example:

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|   |     ip     |   platform  |   browser   |       date       |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| 1 | 127.0.0.1  |   Windows   |   Chrome    | 2018-01-01 00:00 |
| 2 | 127.0.0.1  |   Windows   |   Chrome    | 2018-01-02 00:00 |
| 3 | 10.0.0.1   |   Linux     |   Firefox   | 2018-01-03 00:00 |
| 4 | 127.0.0.1  |   Windows   |   Chrome    | 2018-01-04 00:00 |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Will output:

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     |     ip     |   platform  |   browser   | num_records |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1-2 | 127.0.0.1  |   Windows   |   Chrome    |      2      |
| 3   | 10.0.0.1   |   Linux     |   Firefox   |      1      |
| 4   | 127.0.0.1  |   Windows   |   Chrome    |      1      |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

(I emitted the date for simplicity, there should be dates range like id)

Notice that ids `1,2,4` are the same, but `1,2` and `4` are grouped separately due to the timeline (there is another record that separates them).

To find duplicates, I should consider the following columns: `ip, platform, browser`. If something is different from these columns, then it's not a duplicate.

I can do:

```
SELECT      ip, platform, browser, COUNT(1) AS num_records
FROM        users_logins
WHERE       user_id = 1
GROUP BY    ip, platform, browser
```

But that will group all records without consideration of the timeline.

Comment: What if there are duplicates earlier in time?

Comment: Do you have a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I have an auto increment `id` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  In MySQL 8+, you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select ip, platform, browser,
       count(*) as numrecords,
       min(id), max(id),
       min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ip, platform, browser order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by ip, platform, browser, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by min(date) desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by i' at line 6` any idea?

Comment: @HTMHell . . . MariaDB has supported window functions since version 10.2.0, which was released in April 2016.